# C# Get keyboard input from other application?

Tags: c#, keyboard

Currently I'm working on a project that requires me to get keyboard input from another application not written in C# or .NET for that matter.

Let's say I'm in a game (The game is written in C++), and I want to activate something in my program, so I tell my program to activate when I press a key in the game.

I want to make the activation key to be F5.

Is there any way to do this in C#?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks xxbbcc!

For anyone stumbling upon this, please use the UserActivityHook in .Net